# return mysql error msg from function for insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, user-defined-functions

I have a following function in MySQL. 
How can I make the function to return the `GUID` when a row gets inserted successfully in it, and the MySQL error message, if something happens wrong with `insert'.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fnInsertBusinessInfo`(
    BU_NAME VARCHAR(300),
    BU_PHONE VARCHAR(20),
    BU_TYPE VARCHAR(50) 
) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
DECLARE
    BU_ID VARCHAR(100);
    SET BU_ID := (SELECT UUID());

    INSERT INTO tb_business_info (BU_ID,BU_NAME,BU_PHONE,BU_TYPE) values (BU_ID,BU_NAME,BU_PHONE,BU_TYPE);

RETURN BU_ID;
END
```

I have manage to return `id` but how can I return the error message on an unsuccessful insert?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    BU_ID VARCHAR(100);
        --modify SET BU_ID := (SELECT UUID());
    SELECT UUID() into BU_ID;


    INSERT INTO tb_business_info (BU_ID,BU_NAME,BU_PHONE,BU_TYPE) values (BU_ID,BU_NAME,BU_PHONE,BU_TYPE);




RETURN BU_ID;
END
```

Comment: mysql does not return keyword,You can use the stored procedure OUT parameters

Comment: I Think u r not able to understand my question here